# cURL call works with number but not with variable containing number

Tags: bash, curl

I've ran into a strange issue. I'm trying to script my router to collect usage stats and other stuff. I'm making one cURL to the auth URL to get a valid session id, then another using that session id to the page I need.

Here is my script:

```
SESSION_ID=$(curl --silent -D - -X POST http://10.0.0.1/login.cgi -d'admin_username=admin&admin_password=admin' | grep 'SESSION' | sed 's/Set-Cookie: SESSION=//' | sed 's/; path=\///')
echo $SESSION_ID # 1234567890
curl -v -H "Cookie: SESSION=$SESSION_ID" http://10.0.0.1/modemstatus_dslstatus.html
```

If I manually take SESSION_ID and insert it in place of `'"$SESSION_ID"'` everything is dandy. cURL shows the headers (via -v) and they are correct. Running the command while manually inserting the session id produces identical headers.

I'm sure it's something small. Please teach me something :)

Comment: Try `curl -v -H "Cookie: SESSION=$SESSION_ID" ...`

Comment: You seem to have nested single-quotes in ` ' Cookie: SESSION= ' " $SESSION_ID" ' ' ` (extra spaces added for clarity) that certainly dont do what you want. (Posted at same time as @heemayl. We're basically saying the same thing.)

Comment: @heemayl No go :(

Comment: @Mort Updated to reflect heemayl's suggestion, which eliminates those nested quotes.

Comment: Try `set -x` and then run the curl command. Also, what does `printf '%q\n' "$SESSION_ID"` report?

Comment: @muru Carriage return found. Works perfect now. Thanks :)

Comment: You can avoid that `grep | sed | sed` chain by using something like: `sed -n 's/Set-Cookie: SESSION=\([^;]*\).*/\1/p'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for carriage returns `\r` in your variables which wouldn't appear with a simple `echo` in some cases.